# SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to ssh into a google cloud instance "ajc2" that I was given owner access to. This is the command that I am using:

```
gcloud compute --project "clear-mountain-94802" ssh --zone "us-central1-c" "ajc2" --ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

I have already run through "gcloud init" and "gcloud auth login" successfully.

It looks like the ssh keys were generated successfully and my .ssh folder has permissions set to 700. All files inside the folder have permissions at least 600 or higher. I'm not sure why I'm getting the error Permission denied (publickey). Does anyone have insight into this?

I'm unable to paste the code to serverfault because it thinks that it is SPAM, so I've linked the original post that I made on google groups that includes the code: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/ex8roHMubLY

```
andrewfu:fwdrestartingvnc andrewfu$ pwd
/Users/andrewfu/Downloads/fwdrestartingvnc
andrewfu:fwdrestartingvnc andrewfu$ gcloud compute --project "clear-mountain-94802" ssh --zone "us-central1-c" "ajc2" --ssh-flag="-vvv"
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 35.232.179.72 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 35.232.179.72:22 as 'andrewfu'
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.638568653107616640
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.638568653107616640
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nis...@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nis...@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20...@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes12...@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20...@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes12...@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-...@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,uma...@openssh.com,umac...@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-...@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,uma...@openssh.com,umac...@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zl...@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zl...@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve255...@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes25...@openssh.com,chacha20...@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes25...@openssh.com,chacha20...@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-m...@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-1...@openssh.com,hmac-sha...@openssh.com,hmac-sha...@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,uma...@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-m...@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-1...@openssh.com,hmac-sha...@openssh.com,hmac-sha...@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,uma...@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zl...@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zl...@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve255...@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20...@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20...@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:gO6j1NcV2hOFWMbe+JguVd3iqqV2c2Loo7CD+B4LgJU
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.638568653107616640
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.638568653107616640
debug1: Host 'compute.638568653107616640' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_engine (0x7ff9f540e110), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:W0uL2eaHbndzPnMB070+ZzPHHLDY2v4pgtnPRXHlpc0 /Users/andrewfu/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
andr...@35.232.179.72: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: How was the VM created?

Comment: I see in the [Google group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/ex8roHMubLY), you were able to get this to work by adding your public key under metadata->metadata tab. Moreover, it is important that you specify USER@INSTANCE when connecting to the instance (in case your local machine username does not match up with the username on google cloud). 

To mark this case as solved, can you please add your final observations as a new answer to your question ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're using the proper username? Try connecting from the Google Console using SSH in a browser window. As soon as you're connected, issue a `whoami` command to see what's the username. Then try to connect via ssh with the exact same username. If you try with a different username, it won't work. If you execute it from your local linux machine, most probably it will try to connect with your local linux user which most probably is different than the username on the linux machine in Google Cloud

Answer (score 1):

Notice the USER@INSTANCE in the following command spec:

gcloud compute ssh [USER@]INSTANCE [--command=COMMAND] [--container=CONTAINER] [--dry-run] [--force-key-file-overwrite] [--internal-ip] [--plain] [--ssh-flag=SSH_FLAG] [--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE] [--strict-host-key-checking=STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING] [--zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …] [-- SSH_ARGS …]

I see you specifying only the "instance" part, "ajc2", instead of user@ajc2
, replace 'user' with the google username that has permission to this instance, IOW, the correct username

Your original command:
gcloud compute --project "clear-mountain-94802" ssh --zone "us-central1-c" "ajc2" --ssh-flag="-vvv"

Comment: I am still low on reputation, but wanted to point out that double07robinhood's answer worked for me!